What does mean the ´@´?
I have searched on the web but without any result … I am learning next js and in the demo, there are some code like this in order to import css or icons …
import '@/app/ui/global.css';

I don’t understand the utility of the @.

Path Aliases in In Next.js, you can configure path aliases to make imports more straightforward. The @ symbol is a common alias used to represent the project's root directory, making it easier to reference files without dealing with long relative paths.

As per @UmeshSingh's comment, consider reviewing the documentation.

This is probably a module alias. This makes easier to import modules to your code without having to go back the whole directory hierarchy, like ../../../app/ui/global.css for example

Thank you for your help. I have understood now.
